# A bot script needs to be run to convert meta.[site] URLs to [site].meta URLs

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, per-site-meta, ssl

The Community bot already ran through posts to convert internal `http://` links to `https://`, which is great, but it needs to be run one more time: this time, it needs to convert links of this format:

```
https://meta.example.stackexchange.com/
```

to this format:

```
https://example.meta.stackexchange.com/
```

Our old meta pages on RPG Stack Exchange contain lots of internal meta references which still follow the old (first) domain protocol.

This link points to `rpg.meta` and is fine: [Have links on Meta been rewritten for the new HTTPS domains?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7442/have-links-on-meta-been-rewritten-for-the-new-https-domains)

However this link points to `meta.rpg` and contains a privacy error in Chrome because `meta.rpg.stackexchange.com` doesn't actually have a certificate: https://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7442/have-links-on-meta-been-rewritten-for-the-new-https-domains

> [image]

As you can see this means people trying to visit meta links posted before a few months ago are left with no obvious option of how to actually reach the intended destination. They'd also be confused why an obviously Stack Exchange URL is breaking.

Please run that Community edit script another time!

Reported locally on our RPG.SE meta as well here: [Have links on Meta been rewritten for the new HTTPS domains?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7442/have-links-on-meta-been-rewritten-for-the-new-https-domains)