# NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID when following a link to a Meta site?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, hyperlinks

I followed a link in a comment to a Meta site (specifically, from the comment [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/12107/what-is-the-wall-street-journal-wsj-paper-in-which-the-eval92-and-eval93-bench#comment15607_12107), and instead of getting the Academia Meta site, I got the Chrome warning page: 
[image]

For what it's worth, someone else commenting on that question also sees this as well. I'm running Chrome on Windows 10, if that matters any.

Comment: Just commenting for future reference... this is not quite a duplicate of [A bot script needs to be run to convert meta.\[site\] URLs to \[site\].meta URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300322/a-bot-script-needs-to-be-run-to-convert-meta-site-urls-to-site-meta-urls) IMO. The other question deals with fixing protocol-relative URLs in posts whereas here we're talking about comments. Similar idea, but given that the rewrite script we ran earlier is based off of searching for URLs through elastic and comments aren't indexed... the work involved to fix it would be entirely different.

Comment: Having said *that*, the comment in question was left only 4 hours ago. We could, perhaps, do some sort of replacing of old-style meta URLs with new ones at the time when a new post or comment is made. If you want to rewrite this from a bug report to a feature request, it'd be helpful for tracking the idea... but as a bug report, it's unfortunately entirely by design. We had to switch the URL scheme for meta sites because there is no way to make certificates work with a `meta.*.stackexchange.com` format and provisioning hundreds of certs isn't the way we'd go either.

Comment: Yeah, there's not much to do about people continuing to manually type in the wrong URL other than telling them, "hey, the meta URLs have changed."

Answer (score 8):

Meta site URLs now take the form of `<site>.meta.stackexchange.com`, not `meta.<site>.stackexchange.com` (the old scheme), since the HTTPS/TLS rollout.

There are various locations around Stack Exchange where links have not been updated to point to the new URLs - notably, comments and chat. Just fix the start of the URL you're visiting (you want `academia.meta` not `meta.academia`), and the link will work.

Answer (score 4):

The answers/comments here are correct. We have no plans to support `https://` on these old redirects (as the cost is quite high to do so). These links were *never* generated by us (they were only ever `http://`), so it's strictly a manual/user error case that they happen with.

They are also, in part, why we can't reasonably enable HSTS on `stackexchange.com` (along with other internal domain naming reasons beneath the same top level). If we did that, we'd cause everyone cert warnings as they browsers attempted to load the `https://` version as in the question here.

We have rebaked the network to update links directly to the new domains and `https://`, past that we can't really control the internet and update everyone...if we could maybe HSTS would be on the table :)

TL;DR: don't use `https://` here - it was never supported and we have no future plans to do so. The current domains are fully supported (and force) `https://` connectivity.