# meta.*.stackexchange.com redirection does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, ssl, redirection

In 2017, all child Meta sites moved from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`. According to [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time) there is an automatic redirection:

> We've redirected all child meta traffic from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`, and are now forcing HTTPS.

This does currently not work. That is a problem because many posts on the Meta sites still refer to other Meta post using the old `meta.*.stackexchange.com` scheme.

As an example, [List of comment templates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates) on Mathematics Meta contains 17 `meta.math` links, as in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9755/42969):

> Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8891).

> Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

A [search for "meta.math.stackexchange.com" URLs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=+url%3A%22*meta.math.stackexchange.com*%22) reveals many more. All these links do not work for me.

With Chrome 117 on macOS 13.6 Ventura there is an error message

[image]

and similar security errors occur with Firefox and Safari.

A similar problem with the reachability of Meta sites was reported recently in [Stack Exchange Meta Sites are down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393106/196432), but that has been fixed in the meantime. So this seems to be a slightly different problem. But perhaps it is also related to [Stack Exchange network sites’ IP addresses may change in the coming weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393039/196432).

Comment: Well, they can't keep supporting something that is dead forever. The correct solution is running a job that will fix all the links across SE. They already did it few times e.g. changing all the links to be `https://` instead of `http://` and it went pretty well, without bumping.

Comment: It was already [suggested six year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300322/a-bot-script-needs-to-be-run-to-convert-meta-site-urls-to-site-meta-urls) and like most bugs or feature requests, ignored. (By staff. +20/-0 is decent score.)

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard: According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299086/196432, all `http://meta.site.XXX` (but not: `https://meta.site.XXX`) should redirect, and I am fairly sure that it worked until recently. That's why I reported it now. If the answer is *“That's how it is, we have to fix the links”* then I can live with that.

Comment: Well only a developer can say for sure, but if they really plan to keep the redirection live forever (except cases like this where it breaks when they make major changes and forget about it) then they should reject the request to fix the links.

Comment: We noticed this recently and have been discussing it internally. We were focusing on addressing user access issues but I will check on the status of this discussion. I think one solution we had floated was to replace all of the old format URLs with the current one, which would make redirects unnecessary. At this point I hope users aren't still using the incorrect URLs. My understanding is that some variations of the redirects aren't possible (or require a lot of effort) and updating the links in bulk would likely be an easier solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be fixed now; HTTP redirects (from `http://meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `https://*.meta.stackexchange.com`) should now be working again.

In addition, [HTTPS redirects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299086/335251) (from `https://meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `https://*.meta.stackexchange.com`) now work too. While fixing HTTPS wasn’t the goal (and we've said in the past that it wasn't worth fixing), a change in our internal architecture made it easy to fix, so we fixed it.

The list of sites with redirects is maintained manually. It only includes sites launched before the change in Meta URL formats mentioned in [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/335251), since there shouldn't be any older-style links for sites launched after that point. (If we've missed any, please let us know; it's easy to add to the list.) Any future Stack Exchange sites will not have such redirects configured unless necessary, because newer sites shouldn’t have old, broken links.

Comment: You might also want to change [TLS for meta.*.stackexchange.com, again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372657/tls-for-meta-stackexchange-com-again) from declined to completed, like you did with the linked post. (It's a reconsideration request of the then-declined request you linked.)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Done.

Comment: Also, the links are still broken for the older URLs of sites whose URLs were later changed. Some examples include `meta.mathoverflow.stackexchange.com`, `meta.programmers.stackexchange.com`, `meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com`, and `meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com`. (That's an incomplete list.)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Ah, thanks. I'll follow up with the engineer working on this.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Those URLs seem to properly redirect now, with the exception of meta.mathoverflow.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog and MartinR: It'll be a few more days before `meta.mathoverflow.stackexchange.com` and `meta.programmers.stackexchange.com` can be fixed. Are there any other such URLs that aren't redirecting properly now?

Comment: @V2Blast There are quite a few cases where site URLs were changed, and I can't look for all of them now, but two more cases are `meta.beer.stackexchange.com` and `meta.writers.stackexchange.com`.